# How to hide MasterViewController in UISplitViewController for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios7.1

> I am working with `UISplitViewController`,where i need to hide
>   `MasterViewController` for 1st `DetailViewController`. Means,when app
>   launches,the `MasterViewController`  must be hidden without clicking on
>   any `UIButton`. I tried using `UISplitViewController` inside
>   `UIViewControllers`.But nothing happened. After that I tried to develop overall app within `UISplitViewController`. Here is the code I tried to hide `MasterViewController`

```
masterViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    detailVC = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    [master.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    detail.view.frame = splitViewController.view.bounds;
```

> I have spent my 1 week doing this,but nothing worked.Please provide
>   solution.It would be great pleasure.

**UPDATE**:

> Ok done with hiding master view controller.But when i set delegate to
>   detail view controller,it hides master view controller for all view
>   controllers. Here is my appDelegate's code where I am adding
>   `UISplitViewController`.

```
self.splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];

    MasterTableViewController *masterViewController=[[MasterTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *masterNavigate=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    DetailViewController *detailVC=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *detailNavigate=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigate,detailNavigate, nil];

    self.splitViewController.delegate=detailVC;

    self.window.rootViewController=self.splitViewController;
```

> Here,I set delegate of splitViewController to detailVC.In
>   detailViewController with Nex Mishra's code I am hiding master view
>   controller and when I navigate to other views from detailVC,it hides
>   the master view controller. I know it would be irritating,But it would
>   be helpful.

Comment: @BogdanSomlea for ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
          inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

// this commant is used for showing or hiding the split view controller

svc.presentsWithGesture = TRUE; 

return YES;
}

// dont forget to assign the delegate like this in viewWillAppear


(self.splitViewController.delegate = self;)
```

Comment: It worked when added in appDelegate.h. It hides the MasterViewController for whole app.But, what to do when we want to hide only for specific view controllers.

Comment: U dont have to declare it in the app delegate u just have to add these lines in the view controller where u want to hide the master view

Comment: to hide u just have to go to the view will appear and do svc.presentsWithGesture = NO;

Comment: Hey,it still hiding master view controller for all.If I set delegate to detail view controller in app delegate,it hides the master view controller for all view controllers. I am updating my question.Please have a look.

Comment: i telling u that please dont do it in app delegate do it on the view controller where u want to hide masterview .

Comment: Please have a look at my update question and suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: my friend ur code is correct but what i am saving is that if u had made a master detail view controller and u want to hide it in detail view controller then just place above given splitviewcontroller delegate method in detail view controller and if u want to just hide it on swipe go for the answer given below by ste prescott . but remeber dont put it in appdelegate instead place it in detail view controller

Answer (score 2):

You could use this delegate method to hide the master VC.

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    //Add your own logic to when you want the master VC hidden. 
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set your SplitViewController delegate to the controller where you place this code otherwise this delegate method will not be called.

Comment: Thanks Ste Prescott. It works only in AppDelegate.How and Where to implement it in ViewController.Can you please give example?

Comment: You can do this in any controller that has a reference to the split view controller.

Comment: Like @Nex Mishra said, don't put it in your App Delegate.